# Convert Wide Format to Long Format to Create Pie Chart

Tags: r, pie-chart, long-format-data

I am trying to use this data frame to create a pie chart in R. I understand its best to convert it to long format first. However I am having trouble converting it as I do not know what to put after "col =" as there is no "first column".

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html

Comment: @Farhan Fadzil How about trying `pivot_longer(AveMinsPie, cols = everything())` with `tidyr`?